# I couldn't find the error in my binary search function

Tags: binary-search, pascal

I don't know why this function I made in pascal only gives the index of the number I'm searching for (n) and doesn't give -1 when it doesnt find it..
(i checked theres no problem with other functions the only problem is that is doesnt print the message 'num is not here' when it doesnt exist) i would also appreciate it if someone points out where my code could have been more efficient.

`

```
Function binary_search(L : Array Of Integer; n : Integer) : Integer;
Var
  i, p, middle, first, last : Integer;
Begin
  first := 0;
  binary_search := -1;
  last := Sizeof(L) Div Sizeof(L[0]);
  While (first <= last) Do
    Begin
      middle := (first + last) Div 2;
      If (middle = n) Then
        Begin
          binary_search := middle;
          break;
        End;
      If (middle < n) Then first := middle +1;
      If (middle > n) Then last := middle -1;
    End;
End;
Begin
  Write('num of elements in array : ');
  read(m);
  fillup(arr, m);
  For i :=0 To m-1 Do
    Begin
      permutarr[i] := arr[i];
    End;
  Write('the num youre looking for : ');
  read(A);
  sort(arr, 1, m);
  If (binary_search(arr, A)= -1) Then Writeln('the number isnt here') //this doesnt work
  Else
    Begin
      For i:=0 To m-1 Do
        Begin
          If (permutarr[i] = binary_search(arr, A)) Then
            Begin
              Writeln('index : ', i);
              break;
            End;
        End;
    End;
End.
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your dialect of Pascal (it's been 15 years since I did any serious programming), but I'm quite sure that the chief problem is that

**Your code is not looking at the entries of the array `L` at all!**

All the comparisons in the function `binary_search` only involve the indices, `middle`, `first`, `last`. The first thing I would try is to edit all the comparisons with `middle` to use `L[middle]` instead (on lines 11, 16 and 17). Then your code will, at least, actually be looking at the array :-)

---

Other things:

- I'm not 100 per cent sure that your code handles arrays of all lengths correctly (can't test right now). It might happen that `first` and `last` never meet. I'm probably wrong about this, because then your code would get stuck in an endless loop.
- When I was coding I took care never to assign a value to the `function_name`, here `binary_search` prematurely. In other words, I would not be surprised to learn that your function always returns $-1$, because I fully expect the execution of a function to end the instant anything is assigned to it, so here at the line `binary_search:=-1;`. As I said, my dialect was different, and the recollection is "dated" at best.

---

Anyway, the problem in bold fits your description of the problematic behavior. You can test my theory by giving `A` a value that exceeds the length of the array. Then it should be unable to find it with your current code.

Comment: First time answerer here (and Borland Pascal programmer from the DOS era), but a StackExchange veteran from Math.SE. I tried to guesstimate what kind of answers are fine to assignment help seekers (likely) or self-learners (a viable alternative). If I committed a faux pas, please tap my shoulder, and explain the problem. Peace!

Comment: Yes that was the problem and also for this program to work the elements of the array have to be in order, thank you for pointing out the mistake.